# I want to input variable like string bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix, bash-completion

I want input file like -

```
a="Hello"
echo "$a ${foobar}"
```

Output i get is -

```
Hello
```

But i want output like this -

```
Hello ${foobar}
```

How can i accomplish this is bash script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a="Hello"
echo "$a \${foobar}"
```